Can a water filter be mounted on the tank of a gravity fed system?
I live in a house with a gravity fed system. The tank in the loft feeds both the cold water and the boiler for the hot water.
I know there are water filters that are placed right before the faucet, but I was thinking if there are any that can be placed before the water enters the loft tank or just as it leaves the tank. Saving me some money and time.
Much appreciated.

You should be able to add a spin down filter after the tank.
The filter can be cleaned by flushing without removing the filter. There are even "Smart Valves" that can be added so you can flush the filter with an app on your phone or program a schedule.
There is a minimum pressure specification for best efficiency.  I could not find it in the info. However you can contact the manufacturer vuflow they are very helpful.

Many thanks and God Bless you!
